# Creating custom generics for get, update, delete and post with Django Rest Framework in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-generic-views

I am thinking of refactoring my code because I think I'm repeating too much ending up with lines of code. Take of this instance below I have implemented a class based view to `GET`,`PUT`,and `DELETE` for the `Unit` Model. Later I will create another view for `Department` to do `CRUD` and will follow the same pattern,is there a way I can make custom generic model views that can be dynamically used in any other view.

```
class UnitDetailView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    """ Class based view for Unit Details. """

    serializer_class = UnitSerializer
    queryset = Unit.objects.all()

    def get_object(self, pk, org_id=None):
        try:
            return Unit.objects.get(pk=pk, org_id=org_id)
        except Unit.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        """Get a unit instance."""
        unit_obj = self.get_object(pk, org_id=get_auth(request))
        serializer = UnitSerializer(unit_obj)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        """Update a unit instance."""
        unit_obj = self.get_object(pk, org_id=get_auth(request))
        serializer = UnitSerializer(unit_obj, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        """Remove a unit instance."""
        unit_obj = self.get_object(pk, org_id=get_auth(request))
        unit_obj.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `viewsets.ModelViewSet`. And you won't need to write every method (get, put, delete, update)

Comment: I had to override the methods to add `org_id` the function get_auth() returns the organization id the authenticated user is logged in. Therefore using viewsets would also require me to customize the methods like above so that I add  org_id = get_auth(request)

Comment: @pmutua - where does `get_auth()` come from?

Comment: That is a custom function I implemented.

Comment: @pmutua - then provide its code. It's hard to say, if default behavior can help, when there is no full code

Comment: I understand, the approach I have implemented is to customize djangorestframework's mixins to fit my needs and it worked.